# delete row without the same code in different db's

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 3 different databases that each one contains tables
I need query that deletes row for each code (primary key) that not exists in all 3 tables (each table in different database)

something like:

```
DELETE FROM dbA.tableX, dbB.tableY, dbC.tableZ
WHERE       dbA.tableX.column <> dbB.tableY.column <> dbC.tableZ.column;
```

after the query run all table should have the same amount of rows with the same primary key values.

Comment: Which flavor of SQL do you need this in?  MySQL and Sql-Server are different flavors, and not necessarily interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are deleting from three tables you will need three delete statement but you can put them all in one transaction. something like ......

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION; 

WITH CTE AS 
 ( 
   SELECT * 
   FROM dbA.dbo.tableX X 
   INNER JOIN dbA.dbo.tableY Y ON X.Pk_Col = Y.Pk_Col
   INNER JOIN dbA.dbo.tableZ Z ON Z.Pk_Col = Y.Pk_Col
 ) 
 DELETE FROM dbA.dbo.tableX
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM CTE 
                   WHERE dbA.dbo.tableX = C.Pk_Col) 

;WITH CTE AS 
 ( 
   SELECT * 
   FROM dbA.dbo.tableX X 
   INNER JOIN dbA.dbo.tableY Y ON X.Pk_Col = Y.Pk_Col
   INNER JOIN dbA.dbo.tableZ Z ON Z.Pk_Col = Y.Pk_Col
 ) 
 DELETE FROM dbA.dbo.tableY
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM CTE 
                   WHERE dbA.dbo.tableX = C.Pk_Col) 

;WITH CTE AS 
 ( 
   SELECT * 
   FROM dbA.dbo.tableX X 
   INNER JOIN dbA.dbo.tableY Y ON X.Pk_Col = Y.Pk_Col
   INNER JOIN dbA.dbo.tableZ Z ON Z.Pk_Col = Y.Pk_Col
 ) 
 DELETE FROM dbA.dbo.tableZ
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM CTE 
                   WHERE dbA.dbo.tableX = C.Pk_Col) 


COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify M. Ali answer since there is no need to query 3 times common rows from all 3 tables.

```
    BEGIN TRANSACTION; 

    WITH CTE AS 
     ( 
       SELECT * 
       FROM dbA.dbo.tableX X 
       INNER JOIN dbA.dbo.tableY Y ON X.Pk_Col = Y.Pk_Col
       INNER JOIN dbA.dbo.tableZ Z ON Z.Pk_Col = Y.Pk_Col
     ) 
     DELETE FROM dbA.dbo.tableX
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                       FROM CTE 
                       WHERE dbA.dbo.tableX = C.Pk_Col) 

        DELETE FROM dbA.dbo.tableY
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                       FROM CTE 
                       WHERE dbA.dbo.tableX = C.Pk_Col) 

    DELETE FROM dbA.dbo.tableZ
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                       FROM CTE 
                       WHERE dbA.dbo.tableX = C.Pk_Col) 


    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```